# PHP/MYSQL: How to create image galleries that rotate/change during each page refresh/load

Tags: php, mysql, database, web

I am building a website that will consist of only images on a single page. There are 300 Images on this page. The home page. Each one of these images is a link and can be clicked. I have a database and this database contains a table where the image URL and the link/target URL exists for each image. There are 2,000 image in the database and only 300 images positions on the page.

Using PHP/MySQL how can I make it so that every time the page is loaded/refreshed new images are shown. So that it randomly (however each image needs to be different relative to each refresh. No duplicates on page) grabs 300 images out of the database to be displayed on the page. Kinda like a rotating advert would work. Each time the page is loaded a new advertisement is shown.

It doesn't have to show 300 different images each time the page is refreshed It just can't show duplicates at anyone time on the page.

Looking for a quick solution, ideas, or links to tutorials that I can follow. Thanks!

EDIT:

Here is the code I currently have so far..

```
<?php
    // Connects to the database.
    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
        if (!$connection) {
            die("Connection Failed: " . mysql_error());
        }

    // Selects a database from the previously opened connection.
    $select = mysql_select_db("affiliate_links", $connection);
        if (!$select) {
            die("Connection Failed: " . mysql_error());
        }

    // Performs query to table 'affiliates' in previously opened database.
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM affiliates ORDER BY RAND() limit 1", $connection);
        if (!$result) {
            die("MySQL Query/Connection Failed: " . mysql_error());
        }

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    }
?>
```

** The following code is where I want each new image to appear on the page.

```
        <a href="<?php echo $row['target_url'] ?>"><img src="<?php echo $row['thumb_url'] ?>"></a>
        <a href="<?php echo $row['target_url'] ?>"><img src="<?php echo $row['thumb_url'] ?>"></a>
        <a href="<?php echo $row['target_url'] ?>"><img src="<?php echo $row['thumb_url'] ?>"></a>
        <a href="<?php echo $row['target_url'] ?>"><img src="<?php echo $row['thumb_url'] ?>"></a>
        <a href="<?php echo $row['target_url'] ?>"><img src="<?php echo $row['thumb_url'] ?>"></a>
        <a href="<?php echo $row['target_url'] ?>"><img src="<?php echo $row['thumb_url'] ?>"></a>
```

As is, the code above(the echo $row statements) does not work. The only way I have been able to pull the data from the data base is by putting the echo statements right under the 'while loop' like this.

```
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo $row['target_url']." ".$row['thumb_url']."<br />";
```

If I keep ORDER BY RAND() limit 1 in the code it will only show me 1 iteration. 1 row of the table. If I remove it I see all the links/image links where ever I echo it out right under the while loop.

So basically what I need now: Be able to echo out the $row OUTSIDE of the while loop and it be displayed inside the html to complete the links. And I need it to beable to display a new image during each iteration of the loop. OR if there is a better way to do it than a while loop. Thanks!

Comment: 300 different images is not 300 random images. If you want to make sure all three hundred are different, you would need to devise some way to keep track of what was loaded for the current user and grab 300 random from the 1700 remaining. That would be 300 unique images. If you just want random, order the query by rand() and limit it to 300.

Comment: Yeah, Your right. It doesn't have to show 300 different images each time it's refreshed It just can't show duplicates at anyone time on the page.

Comment: wow! I'm amazed that no one has ever written any sort of tutorial on how to rotate images in a php gallery site. Looking forward to you posting your solution here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about storing all the results from the database in an array that you can use anywhere you want. I also changed the SQL query to limit the results to 300 and select only the required columns.

```
<?php
    // Connects to the database.
    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
        if (!$connection) {
            die("Connection Failed: " . mysql_error());
        }

    // Selects a database from the previously opened connection.
    $select = mysql_select_db("affiliate_links", $connection);
        if (!$select) {
            die("Connection Failed: " . mysql_error());
        }

    // Performs query to table 'affiliates' in previously opened database.
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT target_url, thumb_url FROM affiliates ORDER BY RAND() limit 300", $connection);
        if (!$result) {
            die("MySQL Query/Connection Failed: " . mysql_error());
        }

    $images_array = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $target_url = $row['target_url'];
        $thumb_url = $row['thumb_url '];
        // you might consider changing the next line to include a class on the images for formatting purposes
        $image_link = '<a href = "' . $target_url . '"><img src = "' . $thumb_url . '"></a>';
        $images_array[] = $image_link;
    }
    // use this wherever you want to display your images
    foreach ($images_array as $current){
        echo $current . '<br>';
    }
?>
```

EDIT - to add banner text in the middle change the loop to

```
$counter = 0;
while ($counter < 150){
    echo $images_array[$counter];
    $counter++;
}

// put banner text here

while ($counter < 300){
    echo $images_array[$counter];
    $counter++;
}
```

Comment: Very nice! That worked amazingly! I changed it up just a bit to suit my link structure and amazing! Quick question. Let's say half way down the page maybe after 150 image I want to stop iterating on the loop, put a banner, then start back displaying the other 150 images, with your code what would I change? Thanks!

Comment: I ask because with the foreach you used it will spit them all out before I can put a banner.

Comment: How about instead of foreach use a for or while loop. <br>
Haven't tried this, might not be perfect but you should be able to get it working

'code'
$counter = 0;
while ($counter < 150){
  echo $images_array[$counter];
}
// banner text
while ($counter < 300){
 echo $images_array[$counter];
}

Comment: Thanks to you accepting my answer I got the ability to comment, but don't know how to format code in comments yet, sorry!

Comment: Sorry I am newish to PHP so in that format I can not read it sorry. You can put it under your original answer with an edit by it.

Comment: That also worked 100% thank you so much. I am using all these images across 20 sites and now that you've helped me do this I can install this code on each one an NO LONGER have to have to manually update each one. Thanks 100 times. =) Great answer

Comment: Hey are you still around? I'm not sure if you get an alert if I comment here. I would like to show you something? How I was able to implement the code suggested.

Comment: Hi, I'm still around.. not dead yet! What would you like to show me?